# What is the equivalent of drupal_set_content()?

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks, theming

I am searching for something equivalent of `drupal_set_content()` for Drupal 7, to assign a block to a region. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `drupal_set_content()` is [drupal_add_region_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_region_content/7).

> Adds content to a specified region.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `$region`: Page region the content is added to.
>
> `$data`: Content to be added.

Notice there was a bug in Drupal that didn't allow this function to work, since `drupal_region_content()` was not properly called. (See [Content added via drupal_add_region_content() is not added to pages](https://www.drupal.org/node/713462).) It has been fixed on March 2015; if you are using any version earlier than 7.36, `drupal_add_region_content()` will not work.